# jQuery Textarea - Remove spacing but add line breaks after each word

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to find a solution to this so I'm giving SO a shot.
I'm trying to change the text the user is pasting into the textarea. So far I've made it remove all spacing, but that came with line breaks removed aswell.

This is my raw text:

```
CM 80 326
            CM 80 326
```

This is how its pasted:

```
CM80326CM80326
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
CM80326
CM80326
```

How would I do that. Here's a gif on what I mean:
https://gyazo.com/9734d56834d281801839b29044ad8d96

And here's the code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).on('paste', '.textarea--listofvehicles', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // prevent copying action
    var withoutSpaces = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    jQuery(this).val(withoutSpaces);

});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: instead of `.replace(...)` try `withoutSpaces.trim()`

Comment: @NullDev Thanks for the quick response but sadly that did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the perfect answer to this, but I managed to get it to work by doing so:

```
jQuery(document).on('paste', '.textarea--listofvehicles', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var withoutSpaces = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/ /g, '');
    withoutSpaces = withoutSpaces.replace(/ /g, '');
    jQuery(this).val(withoutSpaces);
});
```

^ This is working.
Why? First of I'm replacing all normal spaces with nothing. Therefore no spaces will be seen. However, if someone is posting something that is formatted in  then there might be the 'tab' spacing included. This is like a normal space, but longer. So replacing that one with nothing also clears that. And it works. I'm satisfied.